# How to access image from css file on vue

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-cli

I have css file with class like this

```
.my-class{
   background: url('../../assets/images/background/error-bg.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

and I got error on vue like this

```
./src/assets/build/css/style.css (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-oneOf-1-2!./src/assets/build/css/style.css)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../assets/images/background/error-bg.jpg' in '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/twin-track-store/src/assets/build/css'
```

How I can solve this problem? thanks

Comment: I'm not too familiar with vue, but does it use webpack here? Just curious because the error mentions `css-loader`.

Comment: I have been install css-loader (npm install css-loader), but still error like that

Comment: Ok so then it looks like you might have a pathing issue. Are you sure that you looking in the right directory for the background image? I'd be interested to see your app structure.

Comment: try: `background: url('../images/background/error-bg.jpg') no-repeat;`